# How to remove meta noindex from search urls on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, seo

I am looking to index my search URLs on Google for SEO ranking. In order for me to do that I need to remove `<meta name="robots" content="follow, noindex"/>` and replace it with `<meta name="robots" content="follow, index"/>`

Sample url
https://seosly.com/?s=audit

I am currently using rank math SEO plugin, Tried installing Yoast as well but couldn't find any option there. Given below is my code for search.php file maybe if we can do something from here?

````
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 */
$mts_options = get_option(MTS_THEME_NAME);

get_header(); ?>

<div id="page">
    <div class="article <?php mts_article_class(); ?>">
        <div id="content_box">
            <h1 class="postsby">
                <span><?php _e("Search Results for:", 'myblog' ); ?></span> <?php the_search_query(); ?>
            </h1>
            <?php $j = 0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <article class="latestPost excerpt  <?php echo (++$j % 3 == 0) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
                    <?php mts_archive_post(); ?>
                </article><!--.post excerpt-->
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <div class="no-results">
                    <h2><?php _e('We apologize for any inconvenience, please hit back on your browser or use the search form below.', 'myblog' ); ?></h2>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!--noResults-->
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $j !== 0 ) { // No pagination if there is no posts ?>
                <?php mts_pagination(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?> ```
````

Comment: Can you confirm that under _Settings_, _Reading_, the _Site Visibility_ option is **not** set to "Discourage search engines"

Comment: Yes it is *Not* set to "discourage search engines".

Comment: Okay, once you've disabled all SEO-related plugins (and flushed any caches) is `no-index` still there?

Comment: Yes, It's still there. WordPress has search pages set to no-index by default.

Answer (score 0):

I missed that this was specific to the search results page. WordPress adds a [default `noindex` to that page](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ac9f6594c40c39c088e83abd232677f4098a4f9b/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L260) which you should be able to remove with:

```php
remove_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wp_robots_noindex_search' );
```

Comment: I will say that I strongly recommend **against** doing this, however. Your pages should speak for themselves in the search results. I very much doubt that adding pages with essentially duplicate content will help your results in any way, and in fact I would go so far as to say this might hurt you because you now have extra URLs now competing for the same keywords.

Comment: Great, We now know the issue but after commenting 
```add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wp_robots_noindex_search' );``` and adding ```remove_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wp_robots_noindex_search' );``` its still the same.

Comment: Where are you commenting that out? Not the source, right, because that will get overwritten. You might need to just dump filters to see if someone else is applying that. Yoast would by default (if not this way, then another way) and I imagine lots of other plugins/base themes might do this, too

Comment: I have my reasons as a part of experiment to index search pages on google. I have strong reasons to believe that it can give me ranking boost. 

Anyway, Sorry for being a noob here. I was commenting the code in the source file. I don't know what you mean be dumping filters here.

Comment: Your reasons are your own, sometimes we’re just curious if people are doing things the hard way or not. If you are truly experimenting, disable all plugins, switch to a core theme and try disabling this filter again, and see if it is still that way. Hacking core is totally okay in playground modes, you just don’t want to rely on this in production. If you see the output, the file I linked is the core file that inject that, try hacking that to determine where it is coming from.